# caffe: How to save the best model while training?

Tags: caffe

we may test several times while training a model in the framework Caffe, so I want to save the best model according to the test accurancy, so what should I do? Thank you!

Comment: Make snapshot iteration count and test iteration count the same.

Comment: I think about it, every testing phase we save the model, and after training we select the best one. But I think it is not convenient, so I want CAFFE just save the best one. If the current  accuracy is not higher than previous ones we don't save the model. I think it should modify the source code, but I am not clear what to do.

Answer (score 2):

Your solver file should contain lines such as

```
snapshot: 10000
snapshot_prefix: "models/bvlc_alexnet/caffe_alexnet_train"
```

The first tells Caffe how often to checkpoint (save) the model parameters and training weights.  The second tells where to store them.  Note that you will also get a save at the end of training.  The files appear as

```
caffe_alexnet_train_iter_50000.caffemodel
caffe_alexnet_train_iter_50000.solverstate
```

... for the pair saved at iteration 50,000.  You are welcome to rename the best set as you see fit, so later runs won't overwrite them.  I usually do this by making a subdirectory **best**, and I move the best-to-date results there.

Comment: Thanks, I also think about this, but I think if it is possible to make caffe just save the best one?

Comment: Of course.  You have a full programmatic interface; you can do anything you like, within the capabilities of your OS.  It's just not part of the Caffe instrumentation; you'll have to write that yourself as an independent extension.